# Undefined reference to `uncompress' - zlib

Tags: c, zlib

i have installed `zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz` , `zlib1g`. I have included `"zlib.h"`, compile with `-lz` but this line:

```
uncompress(datap, &size_uncompress, &bytesp[pos+9], size);
```

gets error:

```
undefined reference to `uncompress'
```

Any hint?

Comment: How did you install it?  You may need to give the linker a hint as to where the shared or static library is.

Comment: zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz with configure, make, make intstall. and the others through aptitude.

Comment: Could you tell me how can i check it?

Comment: @devnull irrelevant, this is C, not C++. Header files don't cause linker errors.

Comment: @user897237 You said you are *compiling* with `-lz`. But are you **linking** with this flag? Also, it should be the last argument to the linker if you are using the GNU toolchain.

Comment: @MadPhysicist On what system would you find libzlib.so? I've always found it to be libz.so, hench the '-lz' linker command.

Comment: @MultimediaMike. You are right

Comment: It should be sufficient to install `zlib1g`.  (Why did you list `zlib1g` twice?)

Comment: @H2CO3: That's not GNU specific. It's mandated by POSIX.

Comment: H2CO3: works... i didnt put -lz at the end.

Comment: Mark - was a mistake...

Comment: @R.. You mean the linker behavior?

Comment: Yeah. The order of `-l` options being significant to the linker.

Comment: @R.. Thanks. Despite it being in POSIX, older versions of the GNU binutils didn't quite respect this rule. (Also, Darwin's cctools happily link executables regardless to the order of `-l` flags. I'm not too surprised about that, though.)